# What AWS Service should I use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

We are currently runs in-house hardware that we would like to potentially move to AWS. Our main application uses MySQL on a Linux machine (200GB Disk, 32GB RAM, 4 Cores) serving content to customers through a hardware load balancer (around 1 million unique users per month).
We also use a 500 GB CDN hosted by a third party that we would like to move to AWS potentially. What AWS services would you recommend we look at to achieve comparable functionality and would you have a rough monthly cost estimate? 
The main reason we would like to move to AWS would be for cost reduction in hardware and better backup strategies.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question needs a lot more detail otherwise your will just get generic answers. For example. What is the size and number of databases, tables, etc. How many DB I/Os per second. What is the average and peak network bandwidth. CPU type and average and peak utilization.  How many visitors spread over what time frame each day. You have 200 GB of disk space. How much of that is static data that can be moved to S3 to reduce instance size. For your CDN, you mention 500 GB. Is this storage or bandwidth. Where are your customers located, a single region in the US or all over the world.

Answer (score 3):

1.You can host your application using two or more **EC2** instances and you can use **elastic load balancer** to distribute load amongst these EC2 instances.

2.You could use **amazon aurora MySQL(server less)** which offers you pay as you go service which will allow to get maximum benefits minimising your cost.It is the very best option for your MySQL database as your users are very high and so as the load on the database.

3.For CDN you could go for **aws cloudfront** and **s3**. it offers higher availability to your application and it also has less costing.You just need to make some proper configuration and you are ready to go.

AWS is the best cloud option for you as it provides service for your each problem so can use services according to your use and make most of it.

It also provides very good costing options whcih makes your tasks easy.

Please go through aws docs and costing before you choose aws.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable functionality would be to use AWS RDS to replace your MySQL database, one or more EC2 instances to run your application, and then AWS Load Balancer to distribute the load amongst those EC2 web instances. A combination of S3 and Cloudfront to use as a CDN.

Cost is going to depend on how many ec2 instances you use, and the size and options you use for RDS database(s) plus storage and bandwidth - impossible for me to estimate for you

But you can do your own estimates here: https://awstcocalculator.com/